# How to avoid gem update error in windows?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, windows-firewall

showing below error

```
C:\Ruby21>gem update
Updating installed gems
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certif
icate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

C:\Ruby21>
```

May be blocked by windows firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [the fix](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) to your problem.

I only had to follow [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#installing-using-update-packages-new).

> ### Installing using update packages (NEW)
>
> Now that RubyGems 1.8.x, 2.0.x, and 2.2.x have been released, you can manually
>   update to those versions.
>
> First, download the proper version of RubyGems for your installation (e.g. if running version `1.8.28`, download `1.8.30`).
>
> *Note*: To find the version of RubyGems you're using, run `gem --version` in the command line.
>
> You can find download links at GitHub under
>   [Releases](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases).
>
> Now, locate `rubygems-update-X.Y.Z.gem` where `X.Y.Z` will be the matching version of RubyGems that you need to update:
>
> - Running 1.8.x: download [1.8.30](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v1.8.30)
> - Running 2.0.x: donwload [2.0.15](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.0.15)
> - Running 2.2.x: download [2.2.3](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.2.3)
>
> Please download the file in a directory that you can later point to (e.g. the
>   root of your harddrive `C:\`)
>
> Now, using your Command Prompt:
>
> `C:\>gem install --local`
>
> `C:\rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem`
>
> `C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc`
>
> After this, `gem --version` should report the new update version.
>
> You can now safely uninstall `rubygems-update` gem:
>
> `C:\>gem uninstall rubygems-update -x
>   Removing update_rubygems
>   Successfully uninstalled rubygems-update-2.2.3`

After following these instructions, I was able to run `gem update --system` successfully.

I didn't have to implement [the following set of instructions](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88#manual-solution-to-ssl-issue).

I think I was running gem version 2.4.4.